# How do I add sheet name for each datasheet in an XLS file generated from "tablib"?

Tags: python

I want to convert some data in my database to XLS (Excel) format. I used `tablib` to do this and can get the Excel sheets in the proper format.

How do I specify names for individual sheets in my Excel file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When exporting to Excel, the sheets have names from the `Dataset.title` property ([source code](https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib/blob/develop/tablib/formats/_xls.py#L53)).

You can set the title in the `Dataset` constructor:

```
dataset = Dataset(title="Sheet name")
```